# How to search in all of my files in my working directory for a certain string

Tags: r, search

I am working on a shiny app.

I have organized my files in a nested structure.

**I want to know:**
Is there a way to search through all files for a certain string (for example: "bar-chart")

**Background:** my app is working, but I get this message:

```
The `name` provided ('bar-chart') is deprecated in Font Awesome 5:
* please consider using 'chart-bar' or 'fas fa-chart-bar' instead
* use the `verify_fa = FALSE` to deactivate these messages
```

**What I have done:**

I went through all files (approximately 30 files with R code) and changed 'bar-chart' to 'chart-bar' but the message is still persisting, so I think I am missing this string somewhere in my code.

Comment: `system("grep -l bar-chart *.txt", intern=TRUE)`. There is nothing faster. The return value is a vector of strings, each string should be a filename.

Comment: Of course, this can also easily be done on the command-line without using R or its `system` function (which is broken in a few key ways).

Comment: Thank you very much r2evans. If i use `system("grep -l bar-chart *.txt", intern=TRUE)` I get `Error in system("grep -l bar-chart *.txt", intern = TRUE) : 
  'grep' not found`

Comment: Huh ... OS? If you're on windows, you can use a full path, on my win11 it's `c:/rtools40/usr/bin/grep.exe`, though that's because I always install R and components with [no spaces in the path](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f). If you're on macos or linux, then ... I'm lost, since I've never seen a unix-y computer without `grep`, a utility that has been around almost as long as I've been alive (and I'm not young).

Comment: lol. Thanks for the explanation. I am on windows. I will try out.

Comment: On windows you could also try this: `system("findstr /M bar-chart .\\*", intern=TRUE)`

Comment: Yeah, but who wants to use *windows*-native utilities? ;-)  (I don't, actually, I find many of them counter-intuitive and in general trying to convince me off of the command-line in their way of doing things ... then again, I'm a lot more familiar/proficient with unix-y stuff and have been using them since DOS vers... err, I'll just stop there.)